# import module after pip install wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a customized built module, lets call it `abc`, and `pip install /local_path/abc-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. Installation is correct,

```
>>pip install dist/abc-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./dist/abc-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Successfully installed abc-0.1
```

but I could not import the module.
After I ran `ppip freeze list` and found out the name of module in list is `abc @ file:///local_path/abc-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. 
my question is how could import the module? Thank you

```
.
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── xyz1.py
│   │   ├── xyz2.py
│   │   └── xyz3.py
```

here is my `setup.py`

```py
with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    install_requires = f.read()

setup(
    name="abc",
    version="0.1",
    author="galaxyan",
    author_email="galaxyan@123.com",
    description="test whell framework",
    packages=find_packages(include=["src"]),
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

############ update ############
it does not work even change `setup.py`

```py
with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    install_requires = f.read()

setup(
    name="abc",
    version="0.1",
    author="galaxyan",
    author_email="galaxyan@123.com",
    description="test whell framework",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

Comment: This problem is often caused when your `pip` updates a Python distribution other than the one you're running.  Try `python -m pip install /local_path...` and see if that flies.

Comment: Are you sure the .whl is built correctly?  it's pretty easy to accidentally build a wheel without anything importable actually inside it.  And note that the wheel name doesn't necessarily match the import name(s).

Comment: @wim I added my setup.py in my question

Comment: `include=["src"]` is wrong. See the docs at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages

Comment: `install_requires = f.read()` looks wrong too.  that needs to be a list, not a python string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setup.py` is wrong, which means you're building a wheel with no packages actually inside.

Instead of

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(include=["src"]),
    ...
)
```

Try this:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    ...
)
```

See [Testing & Packaging](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. it does not work after changing the `setup.py`

Comment: Do you have any packages under "src"? A package must be a subdirectory with an `__init__.py` file in it, in this case (namespace packages will not be found by `find_packages`).  Print the output of `find_packages(where="src")` and tell us what you get...

Comment: yes, there are two packages in src, and both have`__init__.py` in it

Comment: @galaxyan there is not enough information in the question to reproduce your problem.  You'll have to show the project structure too.  Add the result of `tree .` or `find .` into the question please.

Comment: added the folder structure

Comment: @galaxyan This folder structure looks OK.  So please add the following info : what name(s) are you trying to import, show the error of the import statement(s), and the output of `find_packages(where="src")`.

Comment: I am trying to `import abc` and the output from `find_packages` is `['bin']`

Comment: You can not import `abc` because the only package included in your wheel is one called `bin`.  Check that `import bin` should work.  If you want it to be called abc instead, then rename the subdirectory from `bin` to `abc` and rebuild the .whl file.