# How do you create two local python packages in one project?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

My current directory is set up like this

```
src
  api
    __init__.py
    class1.py
    py.typed
  models
    __init__.py
    class2.py
    py.typed
tests
  test_class_1.py
  test_class_2.py
requirements.txt
requirements_dev.txt
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
setup.py
tox.ini
```

I have made `models` an installable package so that I can import it in my `tests` directory for unit testing. I would also like to make `api` an installable package so that I can do the same thing.

Is there a way to do this?

Can you use the same `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg` files? Do you need to have separate versions of those files for each installable package you want to create?

Comment: Please have a look at [`bit_demo`](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/bit_demo) as a demonstrator. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76315388/4865723) by me. It is not clear what you want: Tell use how do you would use `pip install` and how do you do `import x.y.z` in your case.

Comment: You can have two top-level importable packages in the same distribution package. It is unconventional (as in: it is kind of annoying and frowned upon in the Python packaging ecosystem), but it is technically feasible. And of course if you have no intent to make this public, then this is not much of a worry. -- ([reference](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html) I wrote for myself on the terminology)

Comment: @sinoroc Your source/URL is not wrong but out-dated. You still use `setup.py` in there. No need for that anymore today. It is possible to reach what @DuncanCarlmark asked for with `pyproject.toml` only.

Comment: @buhtz That page mentions `setup.py` only once for something completely unrelated to the question here. But yes, coincidentally the paragraph containing the `setup.py` reference has no relevance anymore, not for the reasons you mention (in other words it has not become irrelevant because of the apparition of `pyproject.toml`) but because no one uses anything else but `.tar.gz` for source distributions.

Comment: @buhtz For info: the part with `setup.py` is now removed.

Answer (score 2):

Just one file is required. It is fine to have two or more top-level packages contained in the same distribution. In `pyproject.toml` (no `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` is required):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
"" = "src"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["api", "models"]
```

The strange `"" = "src"` syntax is passed onto distutils, and is [documented there](https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages). For a more familiar `setup.py` syntax showing the same thing, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668058/import-module-after-pip-install-wheel/71668966#71668966).

Comment: `"" = "src"` seems odd. Can you explain this and/or link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: It's passed on to distutils and is documented there https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages